# Why are there multiple routes to the same destination by default?

Tags: networking

When you have multiple NICs using the same gateway/subnet, there are multiple default routes, multiple routes to the subnet and multiple routes to the gateway in the routing table after boot:

```
default via 10.10.10.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 10.10.10.100 metric 100
default via 10.10.10.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp src 10.10.10.101 metric 100
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.100
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.101
10.10.10.254 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 10.10.10.100 metric 100
10.10.10.254 dev eth2 proto dhcp scope link src 10.10.10.101 metric 100
```

Why? How?

When I try to add multiple routes to the gateway to an empty routing table:

```
#ip route add 10.10.10.254 dev eth1 src 10.10.10.100 metric 100
#ip route add 10.10.10.254 dev eth2 src 10.10.10.101 metric 100
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Adding the second route fails because there already is a route to `10.10.10.254`

So why are there multiple routes to the same destination after boot? I can delete, but not add them again. Is there a way to force adding such routes again?

Comment: The rules are for two different interfaces (`eth1`,`eth2`), so they are not duplicates.

Comment: @mook765 Then why does adding the routes using different interfaces fail? I'm just trying to manually configure what already was there... I thought this should work because of the different devices used in the routes, but I can't re-add those rules because `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`. Thus I'm asking if there is another way to re-add the route.